# Documentation on how to use Xodus Query?

Tags: java, xodus

Hello is there a documentation on how to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.xodus</groupId>
    <artifactId>xodus-query</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Specifically, the `UniqueKeyIndicesEngine` to index Entities. 
And for example this code:

```
getEntityStore().executeInTransaction(new StoreTransactionalExecutable() {
            @Override
            public void execute(@NotNull StoreTransaction txn) {
                final PersistentStoreTransaction t = (PersistentStoreTransaction) txn;
                entity1.setProperty("column0", 1);
                entity1.setProperty("column1", "o");
                ukiEngine.deleteUniqueKey(t, new TestIndex("column0", "column1"), Arrays.asList((Comparable) Integer.valueOf(0), "oo"));
                ukiEngine.insertUniqueKey(t, new TestIndex("column0", "column1"), Arrays.asList((Comparable) Integer.valueOf(1), "o"), entity1);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any functionality from xodus-query is auxiliary for the [Xodus-DNQ](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus-dnq) project, and xodus-query module would finally be moved to Xodus-DNQ. Please take a closer look at Xodus-DNQ, as it offers schema definition, fields' indices, constraints, etc.